# Bulk import a list of tables from SQL server to RStudio

Tags: sql, r, odbc, bulk-load

I am trying to import a long list of tables into RStudio. I want to be able to paste a list of table names into RStudio and then easily import all of the tables (doing so manually would take a very long time).

I am able to paste the list of table names into R and create a data frame and a vector that is a list of table names in the structure: 'databasename.schemaname.tablename1' etc

When I use dbReadTable to import any single table using the below, it works fine.

```
table1 <- dbReadTable(conn, SQL('databasename.schemaname.tablename1'))
```

I have tried writing a for loop and a function using dbReadTable() to do this for all tables in the list (input_list, a character vector of length n), which I would like to import into objects with the same name. However, I run into errors. This is what I have tried:

Version 1

```
# v1
# create a function to bulk import from SQL
bulk_sql_import <- function(t_list) {
  for(i in seq_along(t_list)) {
    dbReadTable(conn, 
                SQL(get(t_list[i])))
  }
}
# use the function
bulk_sql_import(input_list)

#Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
#  error in evaluating the argument 'name' in selecting a method for function 'dbReadTable': invalid first argument
```

Version 2

```
v2
# create a function to bulk import from SQL
bulk_sql_import2 <- function(t_list) {
  for(i in seq_along(t_list)) {
    get(t_list[i]) <- dbReadTable(conn, 
                                  SQL(get(t_list[i])))
  }
}
# use the function
bulk_sql_import2(input_list)

#Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
#  error in evaluating the argument 'name' in selecting a method for function 'dbReadTable': object 'databasename.schemaname.tablename1' not found
```

This last error is confusing as the table can be found by dbReadTable() normally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output for get(tlist[I])

Comment: What is the value of `t_list` when this fails? Can you then manually do `dbReadTable(conn, SQL(t_list[i]))` after it fails? How did you populate `t_list`? What DBMS is this?

Comment: @nbk get(t_list[i]) pulls in the list of table names.

Comment: @r2evans how do I check the value of t_list when it fails? 

t_list in the function is populated by the object input_list, which is created by:
`input_list <- c('databasename.schemaname.tablename1', 'databasename.schemaname.tablename2', ...)`

The DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018. I connect to it using dbConnect as follows:
`conn <- dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
  server = "servername",
  database = "databasename", 
  Encrypt = "Optional",
  trusted_connection = "yes",
  timeout = 5,
  encoding = "Latin1")`

Comment: Either learn to use the debugger (`debug(bulk_sql_import)` then call it) or run your loop outside of a function. When it fails, which table? Does one or more succeed?

Comment: @r2evans the first table in the list fails ("object ... not found")

Answer (score 0):

1. `get(..) <- ...` isn't a thing. `assign` is the way to do that, but ... generally using `get`/`assign` are not indicators of solid workflows. Generally it is better to work with a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227). (Functions that rely on this break the popular and effective "functional paradigm", where functions return things and do not invoke [side effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect).)
2. Realize that even if we do `assign(get(t_list[i]), dbReadTable(..))` here, it is *here*, as in "in this function", not in the calling environment. You need to store it in the environment of the calling environment. We'll use `envir=parent.frame()` in the function definition to remedy this.
3. More-so in functional programming, your function should never break "scope" and expect a variable to be available that is not explicitly passed to it. Here, `conn` is mysteriously used without definition. It's bad practice to assume it in the calling environment, much safer to have it passed explicitly (perhaps with a default value) by the caller.
4. Here's the final thing: you are trying to `get(t_list[i])`, which means to "find the local variable that is named this" ... but there is no local variable yet, so it will fail with `object '**' not found`.

As a first cut, this should work for you:

```r
dbfun <- function(conn, vec, envir = parent.frame()) {
  for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
    ret <- dbReadTable(conn, SQL(vec[i]))
    assign(vec[i], ret, envir = envir)
  }
}
```

I'll spend a moment to evolve this a little, in a way that makes it a bit more programmatic, flexible, and robust. For instance, we don't need to count with `i`, we just need names; `lapply` is a little more canonical here, though admittedly it doesn't add *a lot* but is often a preferred way of doing things in R (and is in alignment with the "list of frames" concept I mentioned earlier).

```r
dbfun2 <- function(conn, vec, envir = parent.frame()) {
  stopifnot(is.null(envir) || inherits(envir, "environment"))
  out <- lapply(setNames(nm = vec), function(tb) {
    ret <- tryCatch(
      dbReadTable(conn, SQL(tb)),
      error = function(e) conditionMessage(e))
    if (!is.null(envir)) assign(tb, ret, envir = envir)
    ret
  })
  invisible(out)
}

# your default, assigning objects to the calling environment
dbfun2(conn, vec_of_table_names)

# similar, but now also accessible as `ret[["db.schm.tablename"]]`, etc
ret <- dbfun2(conn, vec_of_table_names)

# list of frames, no side-effect
ret <- dbfun2(conn, vec_of_table_names, envir = NULL)
```

Improvements:

- use `envir=NULL` if/when you want it to just return, not assign
- always return a list of frames, using `invisible(.)` so that if you just call it by itself, it will not trash your console
- `tryCatch` so that if one table fails, it will continue; the error text is included in place of the table (as a `character` string); there are many other ways to approach this, some subjective, feel free to explore this space

Personally, I would set the default to `envir=NULL` and require that the user explicitly elect side-effect by calling it as

```r
dbfun2(conn, vec_of_table_names, envir = environment())
```

to indicate the intent to store it in the current (calling) environment.